# Can bicycle parking stands damage wheels?

Tags: wheels, rack, parking

I mean stands like this:

[image: parking1]
[image: parking2]
[image: parking3]

If there is a little bit of wind or someone pushes your bike when they are trying to park, can the lateral forces damage the wheel?

Comment: Wheels are actually quite resilient, but I'm suspicious of horizontal stands that hold the very bottom of the wheel because they maximize the force that the frame can exert on that section of the rim. I prefer stands with vertical bars that reduce the leverage that the frame can exert.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it partly depends on the wheel/bicycle. Smaller, sturdier wheels (e.g. 26"/559mm MTBs) should be more resistant. With road bikes I’ve observed that they often lean on the spokes. This is especially bad if you have a low spoke count and therefore a high spoke tension which makes the spokes even less suited for lateral loads. I think it can definitely damage your wheels if it’s especially gusty wind or someone stumbles and runs into your bike really hard. Usually it’s also hard to properly lock your bicycle (since you often can’t put your back wheel into the stand if you have a rear derailleur), leading to the sad event displayed in your second picture. I don’t have disk brakes but I could imagine that you could damage them on some stands as well.

I try to avoid such stands whenever possible.

As a personal anecdote, my dad and I used to transport bicycles on a car trailer using a stand like the one in your first picture. On one occasion we apparently hadn’t tied the bicycles down hard enough and the constant vibration and rubbing completely destroyed the sidewalls of my road tires.

Comment: I've seen stands where the structure is between the spokes and the disc brake rotor.  Not ideal!

Comment: I've had my brake disks bent by such a stand at my workplace.... was not happy, and am now careful to lean the outside of the non-drive side drop-out against the stand instead. I hate stands like these, especially in windy places.

Answer (score 0):

My wife's bike tipped over in a stand like this and bent the front wheel, so yes they can.  This was an old 27 inch road wheel.  Putting the back wheel in seems safer.

Comment: Putting the back wheel if you have a derailleur is not possible

Comment: @L.Dutch:  that depends on the rack.  The rack where my wife's wheel was bent was low enough to be below the derailleur.  That may be why the bike had enough leverage to bend the wheel.